# Crystal Reports Summation Error: "The ) is missing"

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, runtime

The following line in my crystal reports formula is giving the error:

```
NumberVar sales0405 := Sum ({sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.ST0405_Ext}, {sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.Cust}) + Sum ({sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.DR0405_Ext}, {sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.Cust});
```

The error:

```
"The ) is missing"
```

The report was created using Crystal reports 11.

The report runs fine when I run it from within Crystal Reports.

However, when I run the report from an ASP.NET web app utilizing the Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio .NET 2008 (Updated May 2008) (provided at http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp#09), this is when I get the error.

I'm guessing there is some change in summations with the newer versions of Crystal Reports, but I've been unable to find any documentation on this specific issue.

I have verified that there are no null values coming in on my test case that produces an error.

The line that is producing the error is the first line of the formula.

Thanks in advance for your time

**Edit: Here's the entire formula**

> *NumberVar sales0405 := Sum ({sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.ST0405_Ext}, {sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.Cust}) + Sum
>   ({sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.DR0405_Ext},
>   {sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.Cust}); NumberVar sales0304 := Sum
>   ({sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.ST0304_Ext},
>   {sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.Cust}) + Sum
>   ({sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.DR0304_Ext},
>   {sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.Cust}); if sales0304 = 0 then
>       ToText ("Increase in Sales:  N/A") else if(sales0405 < sales0304) then
>       ToText ("") else
>       "Increase in Sales:  " + Replace (ToText (Int(RoundUp ((((sales0405 - sales0304) / sales0304) * 100)))), ".00", "") + "%"*

**As it turns out, it's that last line that's causing the problem.** Any Idea why? I fixed it by removing the Replace, Int, and Roundup functions from it (eliminating a few parentheses in the process.

Note: sorry about the poor formatting with that code, I couldn't get the code tag to place nice with the multi-line copy paste from crystal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had this problem, this post led me to the issue which is the function `RoundUp()`.

The function was introduced in Crystal Reports XI, which you say you created your report in.  If you use an older client library (a piece of software I was writing for is using version 9), then the function does not exist and the error you reported occurs.

```
"The ) is missing"
```

I think if you create a custom function to replace `RoundUp()`, called whatever you like, `_RoundUp()` for instance:

```
Function (NumberVar num, Optional NumberVar places := 0) (
    -int(-num * (10 ^ places)) / (10 ^ places)
)
```

This works because the `int()` function is effectively a `floor()`, and rounds down to the nearest integer.  So taking the negative of the integer, flooring it, and removing the negative will result in round-up functionality (ceiling via floor).

By pre-multiplication by a scale factor and post-division to reverse the scaling, the `places` argument can be catered for.

Answer (score 2):

I would:

1. Define a group in the details section for `{sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.Cust}`
2. Update the function to resemble:

   `NumberVar sales0405 := SUM({sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.ST0405_Ext}) + SUM({sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.DR0405_Ext});`
3. Place the function in the footer of the group
4. Suppress the group header

You might have to use the Overlay Section Beneath option (see the Section Expert) to get the layout you desire.

Comment: It's been about 8 months since my last crash course in Crystal. Let me see if I'm understanding you correctly. The purpose of Step 1 is to create a section of some sort per "Cust" (Customer). Then, we don't need to put the Customer identifier in the formula, since the formula will be utilized within the footer of these "customer sections". Then, all we want to display is the footer.. so we'll hide the header and do whatever else is necessary. How close am I to reality? Thanks & sorry for the ignorance :)

Answer (score 2):

Multiple return statements are never a good idea:

```
NumberVar sales0405 := Sum ({sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.ST0405_Ext}, {sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.Cust}) + 
                       Sum ({sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.DR0405_Ext}, {sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.Cust}); 

NumberVar sales0304 := Sum ({sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.ST0304_Ext}, {sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.Cust}) + 
                       Sum ({sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.DR0304_Ext}, {sp_YES_AccountSnapshot;1.Cust}); 

Stringvar output;

IF sales0304 = 0 THEN 
  output := ToText ("Increase in Sales: N/A") 
ELSE IF(sales0405 < sales0304) THEN 
  output := ToText ("") 
ELSE 
  output := "Increase in Sales: " + Replace (ToText (Int(RoundUp ((((sales0405 - sales0304) / sales0304) * 100)))), ".00", "") + "%";
```

output;

The last line, declaring the "output" variable is required so that Crystal knows what to print.  This also ensures the data type is always the same.